# login page not logging users in

Tags: php, mysql

I designed a site and when I run it on my local server it runs smoothly but when I tested it in a live hosting server (000webhost) the site will register a user successfully but will not log the user in even though the login information is correct. and recently the same issue started in my local server. please help cause it's really frustrating

this is the login.php code

```
    <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Crypto-hash.com.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.min.css">

 
</head>
<body style="background-color:  #f1eeeeef;">
<?php
    require('db.php');
    session_start();
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    // When form submitted, check and create user session.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);    // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
        // Check user is exist in the database
        $query    = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username'
                     AND password='" . md5($password) . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            // Redirect to user dashboard page
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
        } else {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Incorrect Username/password.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a> again.</p>
                  </div>";
        }
    }
?>
   <header>
    <div class="topline">
      <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/sitelogo1.png" width="200px" alt="">
          <!--<p><span>Autonomous platform that</span> <span>does the work for you</span></p>-->
        </div>
        <!--<div class="social">
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
        </div>-->
        <div class="right">
          <p id="topline_timer">00.____, 201_ __:--:--</p>
                                            <a href="login.php">SIGN UP & SIGN IN</a>
                                        </div>
      </div>

      
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="wrapper">
        <li><a href="-a=home.htm">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=cust-page=about.htm">ABOUT TRADING</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=cust-page=our_company.htm">OUR COMPANY</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=cust-page=how_to_invest.htm">HOW TO INVEST?</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=faq.htm">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=news.htm">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=support.htm">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
   <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5d4223f97d27204601c8a954/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
  <div class="section hero fw">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          
  <!--        
                            <a class="warranty" href="#">
            <span>
              <span class="l1">Warranty by certificate for all investments</span>
              <span class="l2">$1,750,000.00</span>
              <span class="l3">Full Business Validation</span>
            </span> 
          </a>
          <h2>Autonomous <span>Trading</span></h2>
          <p>Our smart trading crypto-hash.net makes automated trading easier than ever before with unmatched diversification and dynamic logic swapping</p>
        -->
      </a>
      <h2>Let's <span>Trade</span></h2>
      <p>The best Crypto mining platform that designs with a hash function. with our special design alogrithm that transform all transaction with a flexible strategy so that investors are not presurized about making large investment.
</p>       
          <a href="registration.php" class="btn">register</a>
              </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 

    <div class="section">
    <div class="wrapper">
  
  


<div class="login_page">

<script language=javascript>
function checkform() {
  if (document.mainform.username.value=='') {
    alert("Please type your username!");
    document.mainform.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.mainform.password.value=='') {
    alert("Please type your password!");
    document.mainform.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>




<h3>Login:</h3>
<br>
<form class="form" method="post" name="login" action="">
<input type=hidden name=a value='do_login'>
<input type=hidden name=follow value=''>
<input type=hidden name=follow_id value=''>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0>
<tr>
 <td>Username:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=username value='' class=inpts size=30 autofocus="autofocus"></td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>Password:</td>
 <td><input type=password name=password value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input type=submit value="Login" class=sbmt></td>
</tr></table>
</form>
<br><br>
<p style="text-align: center;">or <a href="-a=forgot_password.htm">remember your login information</a>.</p>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <footer>
    <div class="footer_1 wrapper">
      <div class="line-1">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-1.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-2.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-3.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-4.png" alt="">  
      </div>
      <div class="line-2">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-5.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-6.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-7.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-8.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-9.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="links">
          <a href="?a=faq" class="btn">QUESTION & ANSWERS</a>
          
          <a href="?a=rules" class="btn">TERMS & CONDITIONS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_3">
      <p><span>The Registered Office of the Company</span>78 Grafton St , Manchester M13 9LR, United Kingdom</p>
      <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved 2018-2019 crypto-hash.net</p> 
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script> -->
  
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/engine.js"></script>
  <?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the registration.php code

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.min.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:  #f1eeeeef;">
<?php
    require('db.php');
    // When form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
        // removes backslashes
        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
        //escapes special characters in a string
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
        $address    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['address']);
        $address    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $address);
        $city    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['city']);
        $city    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $city);
        $state    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['state']);
        $state    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $state);
        $country    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['country']);
        $country    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $country);
        $nickname    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['nickname']);
        $nickname    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $nickname);
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
        $bitcoinAddress    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['bitcoinAddress']);
        $bitcoinAddress    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $bitcoinAddress);
        $email    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
        $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
        $sq    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['sq']);
        $sq    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $sq);
        $sa    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['sa']);
        $sa    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $sa);
        $create_datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $query    = "INSERT into `user` (username, address, city, state, country, nickname, password, bitcoinAddress, email, sq, sa, create_datetime)
                     VALUES ('$username', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$country', '$nickname', '" . md5($password) . "', '$bitcoinAddress', '$email', '$sq', '$sa', '$create_datetime')";
        $result   = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if ($result) {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></p>
                  </div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Required fields are missing.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='registration.php'>registration</a> again.</p>
                  </div>";
        }
    } else {
?>
     <header>
    <div class="topline">
      <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/sitelogo1.png" width="200px" alt="">
          <!--<p><span>Autonomous platform that</span> <span>does the work for you</span></p>-->
        </div>
        <!--<div class="social">
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
        </div>-->
        <div class="right">
          <p id="topline_timer">00.____, 201_ __:--:--</p>
                                            <a href="login.php">SIGN UP & SIGN IN</a>
                                        </div>
      </div>

      
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="wrapper">
        <li><a href="-a=home.htm">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=cust-page=about.htm">ABOUT TRADING</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=cust-page=our_company.htm">OUR COMPANY</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=cust-page=how_to_invest.htm">HOW TO INVEST?</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=faq.htm">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=news.htm">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="-a=support.htm">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
   <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5d4223f97d27204601c8a954/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
  <div class="section hero fw">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          
    <!--     
                            <a class="warranty" href="#">
            <span>
              <span class="l1">Warranty by certificate for all investments</span>
              <span class="l2">$1,750,000.00</span>
              <span class="l3">Full Business Validation</span>
            </span> 
          </a>
          <h2>Autonomous <span>Trading</span></h2>
          <p>Our smart trading crypto-hash.net makes automated trading easier than ever before with unmatched diversification and dynamic logic swapping</p>
        -->
      </a>
      <h2>Let's <span>Trade</span></h2>
      <p>The best Crypto mining platform that designs with a hash function. with our special design alogrithm that transform all transaction with a flexible strategy so that investors are not presurized about making large investment.
</p>
          <a href="registration.php" class="btn">register</a>
              </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 

<div class="section register">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Crypto-hash Account Registration</h1>
    <img src="images/register_01.jpg" alt="">

 

 <script language=javascript>
 function checkform() {
  if (document.regform.fullname.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your full name!");
    document.regform.fullname.focus();
    return false;
  }
 
  
  if (document.regform.username.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your username!");
    document.regform.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (!document.regform.username.value.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+$/)) {
    alert("For username you should use English letters and digits only!");
    document.regform.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.password.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your password!");
    document.regform.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.password.value != document.regform.password2.value) {
    alert("Please check your password!");
    document.regform.password2.focus();
    return false;
  }
 
  
  if (document.regform.email.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your e-mail address!");
    document.regform.email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.email.value != document.regform.email1.value) {
    alert("Please retupe your e-mail!");
    document.regform.email.focus();
    return false;
  }

  for (i in document.regform.elements) {
    f = document.regform.elements[i];
    if (f.name && f.name.match(/^pay_account/)) {
      if (f.value == '') continue;
      var notice = f.getAttribute('data-validate-notice');
      var invalid = 0;
      if (f.getAttribute('data-validate') == 'regexp') {
        var re = new RegExp(f.getAttribute('data-validate-regexp'));
        if (!f.value.match(re)) {
          invalid = 1;
        }
      } //else if (f.getAttribute('data-validate') == 'email') {
       //var re = bcgHTG787GHggvggRtgr7ghhs;
      //  if (!f.value.match(re)) {
      //    invalid = 1;
      //  }
    //  }
    //  if (invalid) {
     //   alert('Invalid account format. Expected '+notice);
     //   f.focus();
     //   return false;

  if (document.regform.agree.checked == false) {
    alert("You have to agree with the Terms and Conditions!");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

 function IsNumeric(sText) {
  var ValidChars = "0123456789";
  var IsNumber=true;
  var Char;
  if (sText == '') return false;
  for (i = 0; i < sText.length && IsNumber == true; i++) { 
    Char = sText.charAt(i); 
    if (ValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) {
      IsNumber = false;
    }
  }
  return IsNumber;
 }
 </script>
 
 
  
<form action="" method="post">
<input type= hidden name= a value="signup">
<input type= hidden name= action value="signup">
<div class="regbox">
        <div class="leftcol">
<table cellspacing= 0 cellpadding= 2 border=0>
<tr>
 <td>Your Full Name:</td>
 <td><input type= text name= username value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Your Address:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=address value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Your City:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=city value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Your State:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=state value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Your Country:</td>
 <td>
  <select name=country class=inpts>
<option value="">--SELECT--</option>
<option >United States</option>
<option >Afghanistan</option>
<option >Albania</option>
<option >Algeria</option>
<option >American Samoa</option>
<option >Andorra</option>
<option >Angola</option>
<option >Anguilla</option>
<option >Antarctica</option>
<option >Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option >Argentina</option>
<option >Armenia</option>
<option >Aruba</option>
<option >Australia</option>
<option >Austria</option>
<option >Azerbaidjan</option>
<option >Bahamas</option>
<option >Bahrain</option>
<option >Bangladesh</option>
<option >Barbados</option>
<option >Belarus</option>
<option >Belgium</option>
<option >Belize</option>
<option >Benin</option>
<option >Bermuda</option>
<option >Bhutan</option>
<option >Bolivia</option>
<option >Bosnia-Herzegovina</option>
<option >Botswana</option>
<option >Bouvet Island</option>
<option >Brazil</option>
<option >British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option >Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option >Bulgaria</option>
<option >Burkina Faso</option>
<option >Burundi</option>
<option >Cambodia</option>
<option >Cameroon</option>
<option >Canada</option>
<option >Cape Verde</option>
<option >Cayman Islands</option>
<option >Central African Republic</option>
<option >Chad</option>
<option >Chile</option>
<option >China</option>
<option >Christmas Island</option>
<option >Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
<option >Colombia</option>
<option >Comoros</option>
<option >Congo</option>
<option >Congo (Democratic Republic)</option>
<option >Cook Islands</option>
<option >Costa Rica</option>
<option >Croatia</option>
<option >Cuba</option>
<option >Cyprus</option>
<option >Czech Republic</option>
<option >Denmark</option>
<option >Djibouti</option>
<option >Dominica</option>
<option >Dominican Republic</option>
<option >East Timor</option>
<option >Ecuador</option>
<option >Egypt</option>
<option >El Salvador</option>
<option >Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option >Eritrea</option>
<option >Estonia</option>
<option >Ethiopia</option>
<option >Falkland Islands</option>
<option >Faroe Islands</option>
<option >Fiji</option>
<option >Finland</option>
<option >France</option>
<option >France (European Territory)</option>
<option >French Guiana</option>
<option >French Southern Territories</option>
<option >Gabon</option>
<option >Gambia</option>
<option >Georgia</option>
<option >Germany</option>
<option >Ghana</option>
<option >Gibraltar</option>
<option >Great Britain</option>
<option >Greece</option>
<option >Greenland</option>
<option >Grenada</option>
<option >Guadeloupe</option>
<option >Guam</option>
<option >Guatemala</option>
<option >Guinea</option>
<option >Guinea Bissau</option>
<option >Guyana</option>
<option >Haiti</option>
<option >Heard and McDonald Islands</option>
<option >Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
<option >Honduras</option>
<option >Hong Kong</option>
<option >Hungary</option>
<option >Iceland</option>
<option >India</option>
<option >Indonesia</option>
<option >Iran</option>
<option >Iraq</option>
<option >Ireland</option>
<option >Israel</option>
<option >Italy</option>
<option >Ivory Coast (Cote D`Ivoire)</option>
<option >Jamaica</option>
<option >Japan</option>
<option >Jordan</option>
<option >Kazakhstan</option>
<option >Kenya</option>
<option >Kiribati</option>
<option >Kuwait</option>
<option >Kyrgyz Republic (Kyrgyzstan)</option>
<option >Laos</option>
<option >Latvia</option>
<option >Lebanon</option>
<option >Lesotho</option>
<option >Liberia</option>
<option >Libya</option>
<option >Liechtenstein</option>
<option >Lithuania</option>
<option >Luxembourg</option>
<option >Macau</option>
<option >Macedonia</option>
<option >Madagascar</option>
<option >Malawi</option>
<option >Malaysia</option>
<option >Maldives</option>
<option >Mali</option>
<option >Malta</option>
<option >Marshall Islands</option>
<option >Martinique</option>
<option >Mauritania</option>
<option >Mauritius</option>
<option >Mayotte</option>
<option >Mexico</option>
<option >Micronesia</option>
<option >Moldavia</option>
<option >Monaco</option>
<option >Mongolia</option>
<option >Montserrat</option>
<option >Morocco</option>
<option >Mozambique</option>
<option >Myanmar</option>
<option >Namibia</option>
<option >Nauru</option>
<option >Nepal</option>
<option >Netherlands</option>
<option >Netherlands Antilles</option>
<option >New Caledonia</option>
<option >New Zealand</option>
<option >Nicaragua</option>
<option >Niger</option>
<option >Nigeria</option>
<option >Niue</option>
<option >Norfolk Island</option>
<option >North Korea</option>
<option >Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option >Norway</option>
<option >Oman</option>
<option >Pakistan</option>
<option >Palau</option>
<option >Panama</option>
<option >Papua New Guinea</option>
<option >Paraguay</option>
<option >Peru</option>
<option >Philippines</option>
<option >Pitcairn Island</option>
<option >Poland</option>
<option >Polynesia</option>
<option >Portugal</option>
<option >Puerto Rico</option>
<option >Qatar</option>
<option >Reunion</option>
<option >Romania</option>
<option >Russian Federation</option>
<option >Rwanda</option>
<option >S. Georgia & S. Sandwich Isls.</option>
<option >Saint Helena</option>
<option >Saint Kitts & Nevis Anguilla</option>
<option >Saint Lucia</option>
<option >Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
<option >Saint Vincent & Grenadines</option>
<option >Samoa</option>
<option >San Marino</option>
<option >Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option >Saudi Arabia</option>
<option >Senegal</option>
<option >Seychelles</option>
<option >Sierra Leone</option>
<option >Singapore</option>
<option >Slovak Republic</option>
<option >Slovenia</option>
<option >Solomon Islands</option>
<option >Somalia</option>
<option >South Africa</option>
<option >South Korea</option>
<option >Spain</option>
<option >Sri Lanka</option>
<option >Sudan</option>
<option >Suriname</option>
<option >Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
<option >Swaziland</option>
<option >Sweden</option>
<option >Switzerland</option>
<option >Syria</option>
<option >Taiwan</option>
<option >Tajikistan</option>
<option >Tanzania</option>
<option >Thailand</option>
<option >Togo</option>
<option >Tokelau</option>
<option >Tonga</option>
<option >Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option >Tunisia</option>
<option >Turkey</option>
<option >Turkmenistan</option>
<option >Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
<option >Tuvalu</option>
<option >USA Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option >Uganda</option>
<option >Ukraine</option>
<option >United Arab Emirates</option>
<option >United Kingdom</option>
<option >Uruguay</option>
<option >Uzbekistan</option>
<option >Vanuatu</option>
<option >Venezuela</option>
<option >Vietnam</option>
<option >Virgin Islands (British)</option>
<option >Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
<option >Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
<option >Weather Stations</option>
<option >Western Sahara</option>
<option >Yemen</option>
<option >Yugoslavia</option>
<option >Zaire</option>
<option >Zambia</option>
<option >Zimbabwe</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Your Username:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=nickname value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Define Password:</td>
 <td><input type=password name=password value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>Retype Password:</td>
 <td><input type=password name=password2 value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
</table>    
        </div>
        <div class="rightcol">
          <table>
<tr>
 <td>Your PerfectMoney Account:</td>
 <td><input type=text class=inpts size=30 name=pay_account[18] value="" data-validate="regexp" data-validate-regexp="^U\d{5,}$" data-validate-notice="UXXXXXXX" placeholder="optional"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Your Bitcoin Account:</td>
 <td><input type=text class=inpts size=30 name=bitcoinAddress value="" data-validate="regexp" data-validate-regexp="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" data-validate-notice="Bitcoin Address" placeholder="Your Bitcoin Address" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Your E-mail Address:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=email value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Retype Your E-mail:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=email1 value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Secret question:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=sq value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Secret answer:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=sa value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Registration Date:</td>
  <td><input type=text name=create_datetime value='' class=inpts size=30></td>
 </tr>



</table>
<p><input type=checkbox name=agree value=1   > I agree with <a href="-a=rules.htm">Terms and conditions</a></p>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<input type=submit value="Register" class=sbmt>
</div>
</div>
      </div>
</form>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <footer>
    <div class="footer_1 wrapper">
      <div class="line-1">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-1.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-2.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-3.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-4.png" alt="">  
      </div>
      <div class="line-2">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-5.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-6.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-7.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-8.png" alt="">
        <img src="images/footer-pay-9.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="links">
          <a href="?a=faq" class="btn">QUESTION & ANSWERS</a>
          
          <a href="?a=rules" class="btn">TERMS & CONDITIONS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_3">
      <p><span>The Registered Office of the Company</span>78 Grafton St , Manchester M13 9LR, United Kingdom</p>
      <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved 2018-2019 crypto-hash.net</p> 
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script> -->
  
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/engine.js"></script>
<?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to debug your own code. You can use xdebug or at least put some `var_dump($var);` in some part of your code to see what's happening. You say you can't login, is the values coming from POST ok? What's the value in `$result`?

Comment: You seem to be storing your passwords in plaint text - that's not a very good idea. Have a read up on `password_hash()` and `password_verifty()` for that part, and on prepared statements too - passwords are very important as you seem to be storing account numbers. Your login code tries to use the form variables before checking whether the form has been filled in, which should be giving you "undefined index" error messages, too.

Comment: When you say it won't log the user in, what _exactly_ happens? Your header redirect probably won't work, because you've already sent output to the browser, and you should see a "headers already sent" error. One difference might be having output buffering enabled on your server (which would help) but not on the hosted server. But we need more information on exactly how it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this for academic purposes or production code? If it's for learning there's a *lot* of problems here worth enumerating. If it's for production code **DO NOT USE THIS**, instead use a pre-built system with community support.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will invariably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: I'm also absolutely baffled that in 2020, fully 25 years after Windows 95 shipped with long filename support, we're still saving things as `.htm`, something that was only done because of [limitations in DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.